# how to enfore ADT with same type parameter

Tags: scala, generics, domain-driven-design, algebraic-data-types

I have following ADT:

```
sealed trait Event
case class EventA(id: Int) extends Event
case class EventB(id: Int) extends Event
case object EventDontCare extends Event

object Event {
  def test(ev: Event) = ev match {
    case EventA(x)     => x
    case EventB(y)     => y + 1
    case EventDontCare => 0
  }
}

val eva = EventA(10)
println(Event.test(eva))
```

It worked well but now I need to have 2 separated types, 1 use `Int` as id as above, the other use `String` as id.
I've tried to add type parameter to Event trait:

```
sealed trait GEvent[ID]
case class GEventA[ID](id: ID) extends GEvent[ID]
case class GEventB[ID](id: ID) extends GEvent[ID]

object EventInt {
  type Event = GEvent[Int]
  type EventA = GEventA[Int]
  type EventB = GEventB[Int]
  case object EventDontCare extends GEvent[Int]

  def test(ev: Event) = ev match {
    case x: EventA     => x.id
    case y: EventB     => y.id + 1
    case EventDontCare => 0
  }
}
object EventString {....}

val evi = new EventInt.EventA(10)
val evii = GEventA[Int](10)
val evd = EventInt.EventDontCare
println(EventInt.test(evd))
println(EventInt.test(evi))
println(EventInt.test(evii))
```

There are several questions I would like to ask:

1. Is there a better way to inject a type to all members of an ADT? I don't feel satisfied with above approach.
2. In the pattern match in `test` method, why can't I use `case EventA(x) =>` or event `case GEventA[Int](x) =>`?
   Similarly, why must I create `evi` variable with the `new` keyword?
3. Even I've covered all 3 case, why does the compiler still warn me:

   > match may not be exhaustive. It would fail on the following input:
   >   EventDontCare

   But it still run correctly (print out 10 for the DontCare case)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have there is correct. I suggest you define your ADT together (now you have `EventDontCare` defined separately). Also, since the base trait `Event` doesn't have an `id` it's pointless to enforce the type there. So I would re-write your ADT as:

```
sealed trait Event
case class GEventA[ID](id: ID) extends Event
case class GEventB[ID](id: ID) extends Event
case object EventDontCare extends Event
```

The pattern matching can be re-written like this to include the type on the members.

```
def test(ev: Event) = ev match {
   case GEventA(id:Int) => id
   case GEventB(id:Int) => id + 1
   case EventDontCare   => 0
}
```

Typing this, I don't get the warning you mentioned.

Finally, what you observed with type aliases is how things work in Scala. If you define a type alias for a case class you cannot use the alias to define an instance without using `new`.

---

(optional section)

Here is an alternative definition of the ADT that decouples the id from the rest of your entities.

```
sealed trait Event
case object GEventA extends Event
case object GEventB extends Event
case object EventDontCare extends Event
case class IdEvent[A, E <: Event](id: A, e: E) extends Event
```

The benefit here is that you don't "pollute" all your entities with the details of the id.

Comment: Humm Type Erasure would cause a problem no ?